# How to implement repeated behavior when inheritance isn't an option

Tags: java, oop, interface

I have two classes which share some properties and behavior. One such cluster of common behavior is manipulation in 3D space. As such, each implements interface `Transformable`:

```
public interface Transformable {

    public void position (double x, double y, double z);
    public void position (Tuple3d tuple);

    public void rotateDeg (double yaw, double pitch, double roll);
    public void rotateRad (double yaw, double pitch, double roll);

    // And so on...

}

public class Foo extends Apple  implements Transformable { // Foo happens }
public class Bar extends Orange implements Transformable { // Bar happens }
```

Now, the behavior for every method in `Transformable` is identical for any implementing class, and the code required is substantial.

`Foo` and `Bar` each extend different super classes which I have no control of, and Java doesn't have multiple inheritance, so that option is out.

Copy-pasting a slew of code into *every* class that implements `Transformable` is antithetical to all things programming.

The best solution I've been able to conjure up is to create a class with all implementation details, and use pass-through methods:

```
public Foo extends Apple implements Transformable {

    // This class has all of the repeated implementation code
    private TransformationHelper helper;

    public final void rotate (double yaw, double pitch, double roll) {
        helper.rotate(yaw, pitch, roll);
    }
}
```

However, this is only marginally better than repeating the code in every class. While the actual implementation code is in one spot, this is still pretty clumsy.

Does anybody have a better approach for this problem?

*Edit:* To clarify, I do have control over `Transformable`. The entire idea is: `Foo` and `Bar` are completely different. It could just as easily be `Shoe` and `SpaceShuttle`, but both exist at distinct positions in 3D space, and need a `.position(x,y,z)` method which will do the exact same thing.

Comment: Your current solution is to use composition with a delegation design pattern -- what's wrong with that? It looks pretty good from my POV.

Comment: If the behaviour is exactly the same, then add the required getters & setters to the interface and use [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) within the interface. This way, you can deviate from the default implementation, if needed.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It just seems like there could be a much better solution. I just learned about the design pattern within the past hour... so this is a good candidate for it?

Comment: Even if Foo and Bar didn't already extend a Class, many people would still opt for a composition & delegation approach for it's flexibility.

Comment: I think it's a good candidate. An enhancement to consider is dependency injection which can be automated using a tool for this such as GUICE or Spring.

Comment: @drmuelr You can create default method (valid only for java 8) inside your interface with body then all your classes which implement this interface will share the same defined method, see [Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is perfectly valid for Java.  You are actually using the design pattern [Use Composition Over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

As @Naruto_Biju_Mode says in a comment, if you are using Java 8, you can move the implementation to a default method of `Transformable` however you would have to make the helper class have static methods since you can't have any instance fields in the interface

```
 interface Transformable {



    default void rotate (double yaw, double pitch, double roll) {
        TransformationHelper.rotate(yaw, pitch, roll);
    }

     ...
   }
```

Or instead of the helper class, you could just put the full implementation inside the default methods.  It just depends if you need to use those methods elsewhere

```
interface Transformable {



    default void rotate (double yaw, double pitch, double roll) {
       //actual implementation without helper class
    }

     ...
   }
```

Either way, if you used default methods, you would only have to override if you wanted to use a different implementation

Answer (score 4):

Another option, which may or may not be feasible for your situation: Consider the `Iterator`/`Iterable` relationship. A class could inherit `Iterator` implementation without itself extending the class from which the code is inherited.

In your context, a `Transformable` would have one method:

```
interface Transformable {
   Transformer getTransformer();
}
```

a caller that needs to transform a `Foo`, referenced by `foo`, would use `foo.getTransformer()` to obtain the `Transformer`, then call its methods to do the transformation.

A Transformer implementation would extend an abstract class that contains most of the code, but has abstract methods for getting and setting the actual numbers for the surrounding object.

Answer (score 0):

(FYI Considering to delete my post as title says 'Inheritance not an option`)

You basically first create an abstract super class, lets say `AbstractFruit`, for which you still can choose to implement `Transformable`

```
public abstract class AbstractFruit implements Transformable {
  @Override
  public void position (double x, double y, double z) {
    // provide implementation
  } 
  @Override
  public final void rotate (double yaw, double pitch, double roll) {
    // provide implementation
  }    
}
```

Then you can have your fruit's extend this abstract super class.

Comment: I cannot inherit from any common class. Apple and Orange were given as examples. As I said, each of my classes inherit from different super classes which I cannot modify.

Comment: So you have only control over `Foo` and `Bar`, but not over `Apple`, `Orange`, or even `Transformable`? If that is the case - that was initially not clear to me from your question. On the other hand, in that case, I like the solution you have provided. You might also consider injection.

Answer (score -2):

```
public interface Transformable {

public void position (double x, double y, double z);
public void position (Tuple3d tuple);

public void rotateDeg (double yaw, double pitch, double roll);
public void rotateRad (double yaw, double pitch, double roll);

// And so on...
```

}

```
public class ConcreteTransformable implements Transformable {

//implement a concrete class here, you can even put your helper methods in here

 public void position (double x, double y, double z) {

 } 

 public void position (Tuple3d tuple) {

 }

 public void rotateDeg (double yaw, double pitch, double roll) {

 };

 public void rotateRad (double yaw, double pitch, double roll) {

 };
```

}

```
public Foo extends Apple implements Transformable {

private Transformable transform = new ConcreteTransformable();

 //if your orange needs another transform than the standard, just pass the transformable via constructor
 public Apple(Transformable transform) {
     this.transform = transform;
 }

 public void position (double x, double y, double z) {
      transform.position(x,y,z);
 } 

 public void position (Tuple3d tuple) {
      transform.position(tuple);
 }

 //other methods also delegate to the transformable
```

}